# List without nil in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, null

I know that in Lisp a list must end with nil, but expression like

```
(print (cons 1 (cons 3 2)))
```

does not throw any errors. It prints:

```
(1 3 . 2)
```

Is it correct?

I'm using GNU Clisp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have is a [dotted list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_d.htm#dotted_list), which is a kind of [improper list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_i.htm#improper_list).

A chain of CONS cells where the last CDR is NIL is a [proper list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#proper_list).

Answer (score 11):

In Lisp, a *proper* list ends with `NIL`, but you also have *improper* lists. One kind of improper list is a list where the last cons cell has an atom other than `NIL` in its `CDR`. `(1 3 . 2)` is exactly such an improper list.

You can even have improper lists where it doesn't have a last cell at all. `CAR`s and `CDR`s are basically just pointers, so you can have *circular* lists!

In Common Lisp (which is the language CLISP implements), many standard functions won't work with improper lists as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It's also interesting to note what happens when evaluating proper lists:

```
;; A proper list
(cons '+ (cons 5 (cons 10 '())))
⇒ (+ 5 10)
(eval (+ 5 10))
⇒ 15
```

versus evaluating dotted lists:

```
;; A dotted list
(cons '+ (cons 5 (cons 10 5000)))
⇒ (+ 5 10 . 5000)
(eval (+ 5 10 . 5000))
⇒ 15
```

It ignores the terminating atom.

Answer (score -1):

When you iterate over a list you know you reached the end when you hit nil.
What you have is a list with a car and a point pair.